# Speed up Multi-Table Mysql Query that uses Group By and Order By

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I'm attempting to speed up a Mysql query running on Mysql 5.7. This table is approximately 9 million records right now (constantly growing). I have a strict database structure that does not allow for joins (future proofing for scaling). It currently takes 250-450 milliseconds to run on my local machine. I'm not sure how much it can actually be sped up but I have to try.

From my assessment it seems the sub query is the slow part, followed by the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `image_has_posts` (
  `image_id` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`,`post_id`),
  KEY `index_on_timestamp` (`sequence`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `post_has_privacy` (
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_private` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sequence` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Here is some example data for this table:

```
image_id  post_id       sequence
7264      44568969088   1033459621
8564      112520730415  1033459642
9205      44568969087   1033459645
```

Here is the query. The `where in` clause will have anywhere between 200-1000 records:

```
SELECT sql_no_cache 
post_id, image_id
FROM image_has_posts
WHERE image_id IN (40334, 48848, 8993, 32740, 39664, 5701, 53308, 1001, 1230, 24732, 12341, 25777, 94, 56560, 31853, 17884, 16591, 38522, 29450, 31360, 12025, 17799, 17488, 4917, 23317, 9488, 65885, 65175, 16027, 32138, 32056, 56434, 2009, 30706, 36260, 28985, 793, 17146, 22163, 25433, 65046, 56517, 3008, 34893, 34867, 69689, 31359, 19366, 3338, 29484, 49566, 70479, 6415, 19287, 812, 12677, 27023, 17275, 22072, 13930, 25153, 43221, 35516, 14346, 6514, 28791, 21220, 39667, 24438, 3486, 76252, 26890, 30905, 3579, 69546, 4674, 19159, 21693, 36639, 1687, 65678, 9250, 34009, 36514, 13014, 41571, 6454, 35857, 9804, 66333, 16500, 38051, 16759, 39944, 27128, 49703, 33347, 22720, 69, 17515, 5385, 14000, 8418, 6317, 1397, 7340, 3159, 31581, 311, 30628, 9919, 24229, 39407, 33572, 69327, 28745, 32309, 2334, 3988, 13243, 53287, 16034, 29050, 12818, 76190, 2463, 18207, 703, 15259, 31352, 8006, 14117, 44806, 22717, 24661, 15841, 6754, 32885, 9628, 7107, 17055, 49515, 66406, 902, 16878, 14841, 10932, 23521, 8825, 17754, 2118, 36839, 53234, 39556, 9363, 32840, 37663, 9482, 24228, 66371, 49603, 29614, 12066, 37190, 12389, 28775, 7200, 7187, 29489, 28055, 75902, 36348, 25535, 15696, 75929, 10172, 7186, 5218, 66118, 65368, 15337, 2601, 23819, 10870, 24120, 4165, 23426, 4109, 17581, 5102, 23911, 7263, 15024, 31357, 7193, 25665, 8691, 3791, 35934, 11423, 10726, 7595, 9381, 17267, 15641, 16628, 56870, 25617, 66436, 12370, 27873, 9514, 59397, 26807, 64879, 11301, 22795, 29274, 29007, 13281, 27985, 34630, 30844, 40127, 66254, 56886, 27887, 23623, 30851, 23897, 11672, 11501, 41153, 31660, 37927, 6710, 44566, 9817, 39110, 65886, 186, 15385, 3505, 17610, 14921, 10637, 39014, 15465, 26810, 38099, 41191, 32935, 30285, 16141, 3023, 65250, 12749, 35098, 13147, 9023, 2122, 23429, 3021, 76154, 26742, 25972, 32634, 13064, 27888, 14852, 36641, 44748, 71024, 16317, 5595, 38677, 26287, 10207, 44775, 3622, 81212, 36746, 26102, 40813, 6899, 26804, 15877, 37341, 4651, 25380, 14577, 35871, 35949, 65008, 31365, 41919, 49225, 28698, 26809, 31247, 38699, 1396, 41829, 19649, 27187, 22574, 1364, 41778, 41566, 13701, 28834, 15020, 38823, 40614, 25784, 42763, 42157, 27781, 23250, 6605, 29485, 12680, 64775, 65739, 40799, 52682, 59714, 31386, 21267, 32744, 49656, 66499, 26811, 20988, 774, 8700, 20814, 22, 30850, 70768, 33291, 41575, 41574, 9426, 17970, 2207, 4439, 8510, 21706, 45143, 9555, 1767, 7675, 22973, 66500, 30849, 13467, 9328, 45070, 11635, 69420, 44723, 13772, 56571, 7463, 13390, 25025, 21714, 35243, 35276, 59499, 2641, 13475, 316, 2108, 56952, 19032, 26660, 8824, 6391, 76073, 11639, 42127, 2799, 19693, 5196, 69396, 15916, 23509, 39905, 15732, 33013, 66074, 64867, 25349, 2110, 27165, 7945, 28077, 24737, 325, 26806, 3734, 30551, 26286, 18329, 34149, 33497, 18464, 59133, 17617, 49488, 32079, 42818, 20172, 44550, 17286, 35515, 4859, 37661, 24157, 17225, 38128, 16375, 3593, 35868, 41307, 38511, 59500, 27361, 6971, 65555, 2754, 42787, 24049, 69397, 7642, 1232, 23418, 24551, 56319, 11033, 49089, 13267, 22694, 41972, 8186, 19066, 1617, 39920, 26417, 3227, 37793, 11637, 24835, 9620, 19956, 8885, 5658, 11817, 31351, 2355, 37612, 16894, 39570, 15946, 11480, 32961, 3837)
    AND post_id IN (
        SELECT post_id 
        FROM post_has_privacy 
        WHERE is_private = 0
    )
GROUP BY image_id 
ORDER BY sequence DESC;
```

Here is the `EXPLAIN` statement:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "9480.52"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "grouping_operation": {
        "using_filesort": false,
        "nested_loop": [
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "image_has_posts",
              "access_type": "range",
              "possible_keys": [
                "PRIMARY",
                "index_on_timestamp"
              ],
              "key": "PRIMARY",
              "used_key_parts": [
                "image_id"
              ],
              "key_length": "4",
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 5628,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 5628,
              "filtered": "100.00",
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "1601.32",
                "eval_cost": "1125.60",
                "prefix_cost": "2726.92",
                "data_read_per_join": "131K"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "image_id",
                "post_id",
                "sequence"
              ],
              "attached_condition": "(`db`.`image_has_posts`.`image_id` in (40334,48848,8993,32740,39664,5701,53308,1001,1230,24732,12341,25777,94,56560,31853,17884,16591,38522,29450,31360,12025,17799,17488,4917,23317,9488,65885,65175,16027,32138,32056,56434,2009,30706,36260,28985,793,17146,22163,25433,65046,56517,3008,34893,34867,69689,31359,19366,3338,29484,49566,70479,6415,19287,812,12677,27023,17275,22072,13930,25153,43221,35516,14346,6514,28791,21220,39667,24438,3486,76252,26890,30905,3579,69546,4674,19159,21693,36639,1687,65678,9250,34009,36514,13014,41571,6454,35857,9804,66333,16500,38051,16759,39944,27128,49703,33347,22720,69,17515,5385,14000,8418,6317,1397,7340,3159,31581,311,30628,9919,24229,39407,33572,69327,28745,32309,2334,3988,13243,53287,16034,29050,12818,76190,2463,18207,703,15259,31352,8006,14117,44806,22717,24661,15841,6754,32885,9628,7107,17055,49515,66406,902,16878,14841,10932,23521,8825,17754,2118,36839,53234,39556,9363,32840,37663,9482,24228,66371,49603,29614,12066,37190,12389,28775,7200,7187,29489,28055,75902,36348,25535,15696,75929,10172,7186,5218,66118,65368,15337,2601,23819,10870,24120,4165,23426,4109,17581,5102,23911,7263,15024,31357,7193,25665,8691,3791,35934,11423,10726,7595,9381,17267,15641,16628,56870,25617,66436,12370,27873,9514,59397,26807,64879,11301,22795,29274,29007,13281,27985,34630,30844,40127,66254,56886,27887,23623,30851,23897,11672,11501,41153,31660,37927,6710,44566,9817,39110,65886,186,15385,3505,17610,14921,10637,39014,15465,26810,38099,41191,32935,30285,16141,3023,65250,12749,35098,13147,9023,2122,23429,3021,76154,26742,25972,32634,13064,27888,14852,36641,44748,71024,16317,5595,38677,26287,10207,44775,3622,81212,36746,26102,40813,6899,26804,15877,37341,4651,25380,14577,35871,35949,65008,31365,41919,49225,28698,26809,31247,38699,1396,41829,19649,27187,22574,1364,41778,41566,13701,28834,15020,38823,40614,25784,42763,42157,27781,23250,6605,29485,12680,64775,65739,40799,52682,59714,31386,21267,32744,49656,66499,26811,20988,774,8700,20814,22,30850,70768,33291,41575,41574,9426,17970,2207,4439,8510,21706,45143,9555,1767,7675,22973,66500,30849,13467,9328,45070,11635,69420,44723,13772,56571,7463,13390,25025,21714,35243,35276,59499,2641,13475,316,2108,56952,19032,26660,8824,6391,76073,11639,42127,2799,19693,5196,69396,15916,23509,39905,15732,33013,66074,64867,25349,2110,27165,7945,28077,24737,325,26806,3734,30551,26286,18329,34149,33497,18464,59133,17617,49488,32079,42818,20172,44550,17286,35515,4859,37661,24157,17225,38128,16375,3593,35868,41307,38511,59500,27361,6971,65555,2754,42787,24049,69397,7642,1232,23418,24551,56319,11033,49089,13267,22694,41972,8186,19066,1617,39920,26417,3227,37793,11637,24835,9620,19956,8885,5658,11817,31351,2355,37612,16894,39570,15946,11480,32961,3837))"
            }
          },
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "post_has_privacy",
              "access_type": "eq_ref",
              "possible_keys": [
                "PRIMARY"
              ],
              "key": "PRIMARY",
              "used_key_parts": [
                "post_id"
              ],
              "key_length": "8",
              "ref": [
                "db.image_has_posts.post_id"
              ],
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 562,
              "filtered": "10.00",
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "5628.00",
                "eval_cost": "112.56",
                "prefix_cost": "9480.52",
                "data_read_per_join": "8K"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "post_id",
                "is_private"
              ],
              "attached_condition": "(`db`.`post_has_privacy`.`is_private` = 0)"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your outer `GROUP BY` query is invalid.

Comment: This query actually runs so what part would be invalid?

Comment: What is the purpose of that `GROUP BY`?

Comment: The group by is used to group multiple of the same `image_id`. The `image_has_posts` is a one to many mapping table (one image can be assigned to multiple posts). The group by eliminates multiple records being returned for the query. The idea is to only return a single `post_id` but also to return the oldest record first and discard multiple records that have the same `image_id`.

Comment: Are you aware that you have not actually provided any logic for which record among many per `image_id` should be shown.  What decides which record gets retained?

Comment: Actually that's what the `sequence` does. Sequence is a timestamp. So the way this works is that the results are sorted based on the timestamp, then grouped, resulting in the oldest record being retained for each group.

Comment: Is it one image per post?  Or one post per image?  Please add one row to your sample output to show an example of the 1:many.

Comment: As I said, one image can be assigned to multiple posts.

Comment: "results are sorted ... then grouped" -- The `GROUPing` happens _before_ the `ORDERing`.

Comment: So, if one image is associated with two posts but one post is 'private', will the image be shown?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> strict database structure that does not allow for joins (future proofing for scaling).

I have to disagree with that.

- In many situations `IN ( SELECT ... )` performs worse that the equivalent `JOIN`.
- I just proved in another situation that `EXISTS ( SELECT ... )` was slower than the equivalent `JOIN`.
- "Derived tables" have their own issues.
- Denormalization is one way to avoid `JOINs`, but that, too, can lead to unintended performance problems.
- Fetching ids with one `SELECT` then fetching useful info with a second `SELECT` is almost guaranteed to take longer -- upwards of twice as long as a single `SELECT` with a `JOIN`.  This is because of the overhead of each SQL statement.

I am not saying that there any anti-JOIN aspects of the current query are at fault.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for the current query.  From the `EXPLAIN` we may be able to tell how many sorts are necessary and whether the subquery is as bad as I fear.

The things that make this query slow are

- `GROUP BY` one thing, then `ORDER BY` something different.  That forces at least one sort, probably two.
- What will the client do with upwards of 1000 rows of output?
- What will happen to the rows; does the client turn around and fetch links to the images?  Or Paginate?
- A one-to-many mapping should not use an extra table, but rather should be manifested via a pointer on one table to the other.

More...

The `EXPLAIN` looks exactly (I think) as it would for the equivalent `JOIN`.

The `IN` lookup seems to have been turned into a table scan, possibly looking at only a (large) chunk of the table.

Please try the other form of 'explain':  `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Please provide the query that provided the ids and the query that will use the resulting ids.  Let's try to build a single query that does all 3 steps, and see how fast it runs.

Comment: I've updated the question with the `EXPLAIN` output.

Comment: I added some 'More'.

Comment: I've updated the question with the JSON format from EXPLAIN. The Query is actually already in the description and those ID's come from somewhere else that cannot use Mysql which is why I didn't include that code. Everything needed to work with this optimization should be in the question now. The only thing missing is the data and that's massive, so it would need to be regenerated for testing purposes.

Comment: OK, only 1 sort.  I think the `EXPLAIN` says that the `IN(SELECT..)` was turned into a `JOIN`, which is probably optimal.  I would start by not having a separate table for 1:many.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rick. I think you're right in that my logic for how to narrow the results is a bit flawed. I'm rethinking the sub query because that's where the real problem is. Getting rid of the sub query requires I maintain an index without those private results which is fine. This reduces the need to returning 1k results and could only return the num per page. If you're curious as to why I have these strict rules for my DB, it's because I'm going the same path as described here: https://medium.com/pinterest-engineering/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet-3f341e96ca6f

Comment: @stwhite - Aha!  Pinterest was "Sharding", which means some of the data is in each physical server.  This made it essentially impossible to `JOIN` except in limited situations.  I suspect your 9M rows is sitting in a single machine.  If you are hoping to get to 9B rows, then sharding _may_ be necessary.  When you get closer to that, we can discuss _how to shard_ and still allow for some `JOINing`, etc.